# How can I move an image windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How can I move an image with handle manipulation events windows phone 8.
I have tried using ManipulationDelta, this is working but when i multi touch to image, it's return translation, size.

```
private void RectangleImg_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    Image Img = (Image)sender;
    var transform = (CompositeTransform)Img.RenderTransform;
    if (e.PinchManipulation == null)
    {                                
        transform.TranslateX += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X;
        transform.TranslateY += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y;     
    }

    if (e.PinchManipulation != null)
    {
        transform.ScaleX = e.PinchManipulation.CumulativeScale;
        transform.ScaleY = e.PinchManipulation.CumulativeScale;
        transform.Rotation = angleBetween2Lines(e.PinchManipulation.Current,e.PinchManipulation.Original);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}

public static double angleBetween2Lines(PinchContactPoints line1, PinchContactPoints line2)
{
    if (line1 != null && line2 != null)
    {
        double angle1 = Math.Atan2(line1.PrimaryContact.Y - line1.SecondaryContact.Y,
                                   line1.PrimaryContact.X - line1.SecondaryContact.X);
        double angle2 = Math.Atan2(line2.PrimaryContact.Y - line2.SecondaryContact.Y,
                                   line2.PrimaryContact.X - line2.SecondaryContact.X);
        return (angle1 - angle2) * 180 / Math.PI;
    }
    else { return 0.0; }
}
```

Comment: Can you please rephrase your problem? What happens when you use multitouch? The code looks OK.

Comment: when use multitouch this return fist value of "transform"

Comment: Take a look at this [post](http://sharpgis.net/post/2012/01/17/Building-A-Multi-Touch-Photo-Viewer-Control.aspx)